# How can I put specific item in a list at the end of the list?

Tags: python

If I have a list like this:

```
lst = ["None", "123", "XYZ", "None", "ABC", "None", "QWE" "None"]
```

how can I put it so that None is displayed only at end and items that are not None are displayed in order like this:

```
lst_sorted = ["123", "XYZ", "ABC", "QWE", "None" "None", "None", "None"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lst.sort(key=lambda x: x == 'None')`

Comment: Thanks! Knew it would be duplicate, but wasn't able to find anything cause I didnt know how to phrase it correctly and also didnt show when typing in question bar.